# Set background of container depends on the height of the inner box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to implement the effect below:

[image]

I try to set the footer part (yellow part in the picture):

```html
<style>
        .main {
            background-color: blue;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }
        .list-container {
            background-color: green;
        }
        .footer {
            height: 80px;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin-top: -30px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="list-container">
                    <div>item1</div>
                    <div>item2</div>
                    ....... more items
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

but it will cover the inner box (green part in the picture), so how to make the yellow part under the green part. The height of the green part is not fixed.

Comment: what did you try so far? can you post the code you try?

Comment: @fmsthird I have added the complete code, thanks

Comment: the color you are using in the description doesn't exist in the first screenshot, so it's hard to understand

Comment: addìng `position: relative;` to green container is what you want?

Comment: @TemaniAfif maybe just like green and yellow

Comment: @TemaniAfif the yellow background should be the background of the outer container box.

Comment: if you made the changes I told you, you obtain what you want?

Comment: @TemaniAfif if I add `position:relative` to the the green box, the yellow background under the green box part will be covered by the green box.

Comment: you said *how to make the yellow part under the green part.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add position: relative + z-index: 1 to list-container

```css
.main {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.list-container {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="list-container">
      <div>item1</div>
      <div>item2</div>
      <div>item3</div>
      <div>item4</div>
      <div>item5</div>
      <div>item6</div>
      ....... more items
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed my code, how about that situation? if I set background color to the green box's container, the background color will cover the yellow part.

Comment: Changed the answer – now list-container has z-index: 1 and position: relative

Comment: note that z-index isn't mandatory, position:relative is enough

Comment: Correct – I just prefer it to show intend... and I also use position relative on everything as part of my default 'reset' :-)

Comment: @JakobE but the background-color of the green box's container will cover the yellow footer's part under the green box

Comment: Yes – Isn't that what you want??

Comment: @JakobE I see, thanks a lot, this is what I want, so nice, thank you all very much!